# How can I feed third-party RSS reader with Firebase data?

Tags: web-scraping, rss, firebase

I'm not a programmer, so please keep it simple... ;)
I'm using KimonoLab's desktop webscraping software to crawl various news websites which don't have RSS feeds. The RSS data is uploaded automatically to my Firebase database and looks like this:

[image: RSS data in Firebase]

How can I now feed this data into an RSS reader such as Feedly? Do I need to host it on my own website and have the RSS reader pick it up from there?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How did you connect Kimono Desktop with Firebase? I can't find the app secret required

Comment: Also, did you find a solution for the problem? Convert Firebase generated Kimono integration to a RSS URL? Would you share it with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can let you know the flow, It looks strange:

- You have scrapped data in `Firebase` that means you have data in
  `json` format
- You need to feed data to a RSS-reader like *Feedly*

**Problem** : RSS-readers don't understand `json` But accept `XML` format

**Possible Solution** :

Write front-end code to display data you have in `Firebase`

**OR**

Write back-end code to convert `json` to `XML` and give server `url` to RSS-reader

**OR**

Find if any of above two solutions exist.

Happy Helping!

Comment: does my answer makes any sense for you?

Comment: Yes thanks it does! I'm looking into the two options currently.